# Will a 10Base-T Hub slow down a 1000Base-T Switch?

Tags: networking, router, switch, hub

My network hardware consists of a Fiber ONT, an OpenWRT-based gigabit router, and a Zyxel [GS1200-8](https://www.zyxel.com/us/en/products_services/5-Port-8-Port-Web-Managed-Gigabit-Switch-GS1200-5-GS1200-8/) gigabit managed switch. I have assorted 10, 100, and 1000 Mbps devices connected to the Zyxel. All the cabling is CAT 6.

The switch has indicator LEDs for each port to indicate either a 1000 Mbps connection or a 10/100 Mbps connection.

If I connect a 10Base-T **hub** (not a switch) to one of the ports on the Zyxel switch, will it impair the rest of the network in any way? Specifically, I'd be using an old Netgear [EN104TP](https://www.netgear.com/support/product/EN104TP.aspx) connected to a few downstream devices.

If it matters, I'm using QOS (on the Zyxel) and am not using VLANs. The devices downstream of the slow hub would be modern (100 or 1000 MBps), but have low network usage. Do any of these considerations make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The insertion of a 10Base-T hub will not have any significant difference on the parts of the network that are connected to your gigabit switch.

The parts connected through the hub will be limited to 10 megabits divided between them with the added overhead of collisions reducing the available bandwidth on that part of the network.